# External HDMI poor quality

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, hdmi

When pluging an external HDMI display, it get detected and everything was supposed to be working right out of the box, except that when set the resolution to 1920x1080, the display on HDMI is really poor quality.

Playing around with xrandr, when setting resolution at 1680x1050 or below, everything is smooth, when setting 1920x1080 or 1920x1080i, with wide variety of refresh rates, it's the same poor quality display.

Unfortunely I can't post an image showing the exactly issue (low reputation).

Specifications:

Dell Inspiron 14 (Intel HD Graphics)
Samsung TA550

Answer (score 0):

Could you be using a screen that doesn't support native Full HD (1920x1080), but maybe only HD Ready (1280x720)? If so then select the appropriate resolution for your screen.

Comment: Unfortunely not, using the same notebook on windows 7, I can use 1920x1980, using the same display and another computer (ubuntu also) I can also use the resolution, so I believe is something the Intel HD Display configuration.